# Autoscaling Backend and RabbitMQ Queues

Tags: spring-boot, architecture, rabbitmq, autoscaling, consistent-hashing

I have an IoT system around 100k devices, publishing their state every second to the backend written in Java/Spring Boot. Until now, I was using gRPC but I see excessive CPU usage so I was planning to let the devices publish to RabbitMQ and let the backend workers process them.

Processing: Updating the db table.

Since data from same device must be processed sequentially, I was planning to use RabbitMQ's consistent hashing exchange, and bind the n queues for n workers. But I'm not sure how it'd work with autoscaling.

I thought of creating auto-delete queues for each backend instance and binding them to the exchange but I couldn't figure out:

- How to rebalance messages already sitting in the queue?
- If connectivity issue occurs, queue might get deleted, so I need to re-forward those messages to the existing queues.
- Is there any algorithms for handle the autoscaling of workers? For instance if messages pile up, I need to spawn new workers even though cpu/memory usage is low.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'll go with MQTT's shared subcriptions for this case.

https://emqx.medium.com/introduction-to-mqtt-5-0-protocol-shared-subscription-4c23e7e0e3c1

> Sharing strategy
>
> Although shared subscriptions allow subscribers to consume messages in
> a load-balanced manner, the MQTT protocol does not specify what
> load-balancing strategy the server should use. For reference, EMQ X
> provides four strategies for users to choose: random, round_robin,
> sticky, and hash.
>
> ```
> random: randomly select one in all shared subscription sessions to publish messages
> round_robin: select in turn according to subscription order
> sticky: use a random strategy to randomly select a subscription session, continue to use the session until the subscription is cancelled or disconnect and repeat the process
> hash: Hash the ClientID of the sender, and select a subscription session based on the hash result
> ```

`Hash` seems like what I'm looking for.